# What to expect from canned bear meat?

Tags: meat, canning, bear

I aquired a can of bear meat from Finland. I'm not sure what to expect of the contents of the can. Will the meat be pre-cooked?

I can find some ideas online for preperation of fresh bear meat, but grilling probably doesn't translate too well for canned meat. What are normal preparations for canned bear meat?

Comment: I've purchased canned reindeer and elk from Finland. Ideal for stews or to heat and pair with veggies. Some items I've had already had veggies in them, from the cooking process, I guess.

Comment: @logophobe it doesn't answer the title or the second paragraph, so I didn't, but I suppose not many people will have general guidance on cooking bear.

Comment: @ChrisH that not many people have general guidance cooking bear is exactly why I asked here :D - still good info on the canning though.

Comment: @ChrisH I'd suggest that those fall under the heading of "too broad" and should be removed from the question in the first place, as they'll just produce a list of suggestions about what you *could* hypothetically do with canned meat.

Comment: @logophobe or recipe request of course.  I've tried to avoid too much guesswork anyway

Comment: A brief Reddit thread says "treat it like pork", which sounds reasonable.

Comment: Please let us know what you decide to do and how it turns out! I'm particularly interested to know the doneness(?) of the meat when you open the can. All of the canned meat products I've had were falling apart tender right out of the can.

Comment: The can is almost certain to have a list of ingredients which would give you an idea of what to expect. if you can identify that on the can, using an online translator may be useful.

Comment: Hopefully it won't end up tasting like pooh.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Canned foods are by their very nature cooked once they're in the can.  That's how they keep so well.  It is possible to grill canned meat if you dry it first, and it may benefit from a little browning for best flavour (assuming this wasn't done before canning).